# Socks proxy over WinRM Tunnels

Tags: socks, winrm, tunneling

We have Windows machine acting as WinRM server and a Linux machine acting as WinRM client, with PyWinRM.

Our Linux machine hosts a program that runs a remote program on the windows Host, over WinRM.

We are not allowed to install any extra package on the Windows Host.

The Windows host can't reach any other host, all the outgoing requests are blocked by firewall. Let's say that only Incoming TCP on WinRM port is allowed.

Is it possible to make a reverse tunnel over the winrm incoming traffic that makes our windows host communicates with the external world over the linux host over a TCP socks proxy.

This is possible by SSH, over tunneling, but is it possible over WinRM ?

Any solution please ?

Regards,